# python find the num in list greater than left and right

Tags: python

The question is use iterator to find the num from list who is greater than the nums in left and right

For example, select([0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0]) return [1,2,3,4]

My first try is

```
def select(iterable):
    answer = []
    it = iter(iterable)

    try:
        v2 = next(it)
        while True:
            v1,v2= v2,next(it)
            if v2>v1 and v2>next(it):
                answer.append(v2)
    except StopIteration:
         pass
    return answer
```

This code fails.
I think the next(it) in the while loop would be the same iterator,but the next() still iter next one in the code.

then I change the code to below one, it works.

```
try:
    v1,v2,v3 = next(it),next(it),next(it)
    while True:
        if v2>v1 and v2>v3:
            answer.append(v2)
        v1,v2,v3 = v2,v3,next(it)
except StopIteration:
     pass
```

Can someone explain what is difference happen here?

Comment: you could do this quite easily using enumerate

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the first snippet:

1. Every time you call `next(it)`, it advances the iterator. You have to store the returned value if you want to access it more than once. Calling `next(it)` again won't do that; it will advance the iterator yet again.
2. Even if the first point weren't an issue, the following would still be problematic:

   ```
       if v2>v1 and v2>next(it):
   ```

   The issue here is [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Depending on whether `v2>v1`, this may or may not advance the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in this line:

```
if v2>v1 and v2>next(it):
```

Your calling next(it), but you don't store the return value. You just compare it to the v2. So the value gets skipped.

edit:

Btw, if you compare multiple values, the following comparison is much more cleaner:

```
 if v1 < v2 > v3:
```